# FatalError ошибки с mysql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте пользователи данного форума. Я столкнулся с проблемой. Я не являюсь разработчиком или тем, кто шарит в MySQL и т.д. Просто, если кратко говорить, то создатель проекта одного. Дело не в этом

Проблема в том, что на форуме нашей игры появилась вот такая странная ошибка

> Fatal error: Uncaught XF\Db\Exception:
> Access denied for user 'u227894_KBCP'@'78.108.80.33' (using password: YES) in /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/Db/Mysqli/Adapter.php:165 Stack trace: #0 /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/Db/Mysqli/Adapter.php(28): XF\Db\Mysqli\Adapter->makeConnection(Array) #1 /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/Db/AbstractAdapter.php(60): XF\Db\Mysqli\Adapter->getConnection() #2 /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/Db/Mysqli/Adapter.php(113): XF\Db\AbstractAdapter->connect() #3 /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/Db/AbstractAdapter.php(516): XF\Db\Mysqli\Adapter->escapeString('options') #4 /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/Db/AbstractAdapter.php(494): XF\Db\AbstractAdapter->quote('options') #5 /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/DataRegistry.php(138):
> XF\Db\AbstractAdapter->quote(Array) #6 /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/DataRegistry.php(83): XF\DataRegistry->readFromDb(Array, Array) #7 /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/DataRegistry.php(226):
> XF\DataRe in /home/u227894/blaze.rp.forum/www/src/XF/Db/Mysqli/Adapter.php on line 165

Проблему уже очень долго не могу пофиксить, а нанимать програмиста денег нет(. Если кто знает, подскажите что нужно сделать? Хотя я предполагаю, что это не решается одним действием.

Comment: Ну в первой же строке указана причина - доступ запрещён. Наиболее вероятная причина - смена IP хоста, на котором вертится PHP-сервер.

Comment: Ошибка временного характера или постоянная?

Comment: Нет. Ошибка постоянная.

Comment: Ну, по идее не должен был смениться IP сервера хоста, но я много чего не понимаю. Что мне стоит проверить?

Comment: Я хоть и не понимаю, но может интуитивно хотя бы догадаюсь )